# How do i place text in the middle of an image in html?

Tags: html, css

This is my html code

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="content" style="display: flex">
            <img src="/img/logo.png">
            <p style="margin-left: 40px">YukinoMusic</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the image below shows what I am trying to achieve

[image: Here's the image]

Comment: do u mean like, `How to put the text in the middle of an Image?`

Comment: [this is what i meant](https://i.imgur.com/PqQZSdq.png)

Comment: <div class="content" style="display: flex;align-items: center;">

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `justify-content` and `align-items` to manipulate the positioning of the children from `.content` selector. Set `justify-content` to `left` and `align-items` to `center`

```
.content {
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content" style="display: flex; align-items:center;">
      <img src="/img/logo.png">
      <p style="margin-left: 40px">YukinoMusic</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do what you want

The best one is probably using your logo as a background image

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjC4H.png");
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 2rem;;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  YukinoMusic
</div>
```

But you can also use different divs and position them as you want

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
}
#text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjC4H.png">
      <div id="text">YukinoMusic</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this is a CSS question, not a HTML question. CSS is concerned with the styling of your webpage, and therefore your question is in the realm of CSS, not HTML, which only describes content and structure.

The way I would do it is

1. set the position attribute to absolute - this allows positioning outside of the normal flow of content
2. place the left side of the text in the horizontal middle of its parent (in your case the div it is in)
3. translate the text to the left by 50% of the width, to center the middle of the text, not the left side.

```html
<p style="position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%)">"Hallo Welt"</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how, just set the margin to be `auto`.
Remember, first value is up&down and the second is left&right

`margin: up&down left&right`

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}

.content {
  border: solid white 2px;
  display: flex;
}

.content > img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.p1 {
  color: white;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.p2 {
  color: white;
  margin: auto 200px;
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/63/a2/46/63a2469a6f9557da638b1c75d56b1554.jpg" width="200px">
             <p class="p1">YukinoMusic</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/ab/63/55/ab63556093e53148bc947e63bb9b262a.jpg" width="200px">
            <p class="p2">YukinoMusic</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```